# How to display information from a website on my discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im building a discord bot(Javascript, Node.js, Discord.js) which is based on a game (a online multiplayer).So, im pretty much done developing the bot except for one thing which I really wish I could add. So, this game has some highscores which can be viewed here - https://www.hzgaming.net/high.php . So, I want to display those highscores (Highscore money - https://www.hzgaming.net/high.php?scores=money) (Highscore materials - https://www.hzgaming.net/high.php?scores=materials) and all those. So, what I would like to have is..when a user types a cmd like '!highscore money', it should show the highscore available on that website link I gave above, and similarly..when they use '!highscore materials' it should show the highscore of materials from that link respectivly. I want it to be from that link because, it keeps on  changing and gets updated. Also, im pretty sure its possible because, there is a similar bot which shows the same thing as I explained. I hope you understood what I meant. I would really love to get an answer for this, also it would be great if an example code is provided with the answer so that its easy to understand.

An example for the cmd is given below -

user - !highscore money
BOT - Money High Scores

1. Celia_Fernandz - $41,085,610 total wealth
2. Armando_Domrani - $40,204,664 total wealth
3. Sergio_Box - $38,199,486 total wealth
4. Tony_Sativa - $30,193,261 total wealth
5. Aminox_Trigui - $28,052,188 total wealth
6. Ben_Martin - $23,439,003 total wealth
7. Daryl_Grimes - $17,128,518 total wealth
8. Luccas_Von_Koening - $16,457,964 total wealth
9. Charlie_Hustle - $14,452,056 total wealth
10. Kevin_Maddox - $13,630,605 total wealth

user- !highscore materials
BOT -     1. Chapo_Diamond - 5,749,300 materials
2. Van_Damme - 4,923,046 materials
3. Brandon_Heath_Tsung - 3,906,395 materials
4. Armando_Domrani - 3,241,925 materials
5. Tazz_Equinox - 3,187,045 materials
6. Danny_Ted - 2,868,088 materials
7. Jack_Paterson - 2,748,249 materials
8. John_Dixon - 2,548,250 materials
9. Gab_Alphonse - 2,252,285 materials
10. Don_Thomax - 2,131,177 materials
((**ALL THE REPLY BY THE BOT WILL BE EMBEDS**))
(yea, so somehow those values should keep on updating, thats why I gave the link above)

Pls note that the code should be javascript using discord.js and node.js. Thank you <3 :)

Comment: The most important thing is to use that link, because just using the given info wont work since the highscores of the game keeps changing and therefore, the info should also change auto. (The link provided keep updating the highscores )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's possible because of the "Just checking your computer, this will only take a few seconds" page that will always pop up (for `DDoS` protection). For example, this is what I got in my console after requesting some data:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
                <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="12">
                <link rel="Shortcut Icon" href="https://www.hzgaming.net/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
                <title>Just a moment...</title>
                <style>@font-face{font-family:Open Sans;font-style:normal;font-weight:400;font-display:swap;src:local("Open Sans Regular"),local("OpenSans-Regular"),url(data:font/woff2;base64,
d09GMgABAAAAACjgAA4AAAAAUhQAACiIAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGiIbEBwaBmAAZBEQCoGANONLC4
M8AAE2AiQDhnAEIAWDWgeQShv4QBXjmFXAxsEAi709IypHX42iQhIH/39MoGOIFG6KqtsXWLsNGTEJswgLuVELAuzt
6BPcQHcKGcv5HKXdi+eKlYT6O/H7D3cgR+jqXNVLasoPuSn55q2H3pbvh3OAu9IvBQY5QmOf5EL/td9nz5tz7szuhl
FHoURhUQJqVpEko1I+Ki4WZRSx2vo+qLaiHszxbb7Ne0BkhgdhTe1mgqThm6figcxKku0p+W2vqybIl4ofbmvDwzr/

// and so on... for a very long time.
```

---

I don't think there's a way to get past this, but in the miraculous chance you find a way, this is how I would get the needed data:

```js
// you should use this npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://www.hzgaming.net/high.php?scores=money')
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((body) => console.log(body));
```

Comment: Hey! I tried the second code you sent, and this is what it showed

Comment: ReferenceError: res is not defined

Comment: Im sorry,but can you tell me what I am supposed to do?

Comment: Did you install the npm package?

Comment: Yes, I did... I used npm install node-fetch in the terminal and yes, It was installed

Comment: Am I supposed to define res and Body? somewhere as a const or in any .json file?

Comment: No, you do not need to define parameters for callbacks. Could you show your code?

Comment: Hey, I tried the code, but its showed up as you said. So, I just left it..but It would be really appreciated if you can help me with this cmd( which I guess is pretty easy, but idk how to make it) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63562936/how-to-show-info-from-a-file-text-real-time-on-my-discord-bot